# reset robot location in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Normally when opening RViz, my robot starts at 0, 0, 0. Then I move it, and then I'd like to reset it back to 0, 0, 0 without closing and then reopening RViz and, *I think*, restarting ros core.

How does one reset the robot in RViz to start back at 0, 0, 0 while it's running?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274683/reset-robot-location-in-rviz/) by [SRD](https://answers.ros.org/users/27821/srd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2017-10-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can delete the model and respawn it. Have a look at how to spawn model [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_roslaunch).

You can also use python script to do it for your. In [gazebo_ros_pkgs](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs) package there is [spawn_model](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/blob/kinetic-devel/gazebo_ros/scripts/spawn_model) python script that takes care of it (it's the same one used with `roslaunch` command).

You can spawn model using python like this:

```
from gazebo_msgs.srv import SpawnModel

def spawn():
    req = SpawnModelRequest()
    req.model_name = "model"
    req.model_xml = model_xml
    req.robot_namespace = "namespace"
    req.initial_pose.position.x = 0.0
    req.initial_pose.position.y = 0.0
    req.initial_pose.position.z = 0.0
    req.initial_pose.orientation.x = 0.0
    req.initial_pose.orientation.y = 0.0
    req.initial_pose.orientation.z = 0.0
    req.initial_pose.orientation.w = 1.0
    req.reference_frame = ''

    try:
        srv = ServiceProxy('/gazebo/spawn_sdf_model', SpawnModel)
        resp = srv(req)
    except ServiceException, e:
        print("   Service call failed: %s" % e)
        sys.exit(1)

    if resp.success:
        print(resp.status_message)
        return 0
    else:
        print(resp.status_message)
        return 1
```

Where `model_xml` is your `urdf` or `sdf` file.

Then you can delete models like this:

```
def delete():
    try:
        srv = ServiceProxy('/gazebo/delete_model', DeleteModel)
        req = DeleteModelRequest()
        req.model_name = "model"
        resp = srv(req)
    except ServiceException, e:
        print("Service call failed: %s" % e)
        sys.exit(2)
    
    if resp.success:
        print(resp.status_message)
        return 0
    else:
        print(resp.status_message)
        return 1
```

So if you want you can create your own python script which takes care of it. Using `roslaunch` command is fine as well, but you're limited sometimes.

---

Originally posted by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) with karma: 826 on 2017-11-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0